# Pandas join results in mismatch shape

Tags: python, pandas, join

I have two dataframes:

Frame A:

```
OB_ID    CA_ID    col1    col2    col3
4         4        a       b       c
4         4        a       d       b
3         5        c       c       e
```

this dataframe is very large and I am not sure about all the IDs in it.

Frame B:

```
OB_ID    CA_ID    colZ
1         1        sky
4         4        fire
4         3        data
```

I want to add the colZ to frame A only if OB_ID and CA_ID matches, otherwise add Nan/NUll in that palce, resulting dataframe to look like this:

```
OB_ID    CA_ID    col1    col2    col3    colz
4         4        a       b       c       fire
4         4        a       d       b       fire
3         5        c       c       e       NA/unknown
```

The shape of Frame A is 8666515 rows × 3 columns, and for B is 367469 rows × 342 columns, but when I do

```
df3 = pd.merge(frameA, frameB, on=['OB_ID','CA_ID'], how='left')
df3.shape
```

it gives shape: `1490420 rows × 343 columns`, but I dnt understand why the number of rows grow from 367469  to 1490420 .

Comment: "only if OB_ID and CA_ID matches" ... what? Each other, like OB_ID == CA_ID? Or if there is the same pair [OB_ID; CA_ID] in both dataframes?

Comment: If its the same pair in both dataframe.

Comment: If you're merging with 'left', and the first frame is `frameA` of length 8_666_515, then you couldn't get a smaller length: 1_490_420. Maybe you mixed up the lengths of your dataframes?

Comment: this likely means you have duplicates in frameB, what gives `frameB.duplicated(['OB_ID','CA_ID']).sum()?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resultant number of rows after left-merge is greater than that of *left* dataframe because of nonunique entries in the `on` part, i.e., the `["OB_ID", "CA_ID"]` columns of the left frame, and how pandas tries to *align* things. For example, frameA has the pair `[4, 4]` two times. If the frameB, say, has it 3 times, then the alignment procedure dictates that the resultant frame after merge will have 2 x 3 = 6 `[4, 4]` rows, i.e., the cross product will be taken. (Note: i hope the example `[4, 4]` isn't confusing: it's *not* that 4 is repeated twice there; it's that `[4, 4]` as a *pair*/*row* is repeated twice.)

This is a theme that resonates over pandas:

```py
>>> pd.Series([12, 3], index=[0, 0]) + pd.Series([40, 50, 60], index=[0, 0, 0])
```

What would you say about the index & size of the result of this summation? Yes it is 2 x 3 = 6 zeros.

Back to the question... Instead of merging, we can `map` the frameA's related column values, right? And the `mapper` would be frameB modified slightly: a Series is kind of a dictionary (mapping) whose index are the "keys" and the "values", well, the corresponding values. So we will make `["OB_ID", "CA_ID"]` the index, `"colZ"` the values; that will make `mapper`. Thing is, we cannot directly map `df[["OB_ID", "CA_ID"]]`... because a DataFrame isn't directly mappable. But a MultiIndex is! So here we go:

```py
common_cols         = ["OB_ID", "CA_ID"]
target_col          = "colZ"
mapper              = frame_B.set_index(common_cols )[target_col]
frame_A[target_col] = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(frame_A[common_cols]).map(mapper)
```

to get

```py
>>> frame_A

   OB_ID  CA_ID col1 col2 col3  colZ
0      4      4    a    b    c  fire
1      4      4    a    d    b  fire
2      3      5    c    c    e   NaN
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the elaborate answer :) I appreciate it.

I tried this, but gives error:
InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Comment: Hi @Obiii! Welp... that's a *data* problem :p Meaning: for example, your `frameB` has a row `4         3        data` okay; but it *also* has `4         3        other`; in this case, how should the poor `4 3` value of `frameA` be mapped to? to `data` or to `other`?

Comment: IOW, it's like you're trying to have duplicate keys in a Python dictionary.

Comment: and a way to resolve this, for example, is to drop_duplicates in `common_cols` in `frameB` before making a `mapper` out of it, e.g., `mapper = frameB.drop_duplicates(subset=common_cols).set_index(...)[...]`. Note that this will keep  the first occurence, and will drop the others.

Comment: I will try this, how do I check if frameB has multiple values for same OB_ID and CA_ID?

Comment: `frame_B[frame_B.duplicated(subset=common_cols, keep=False)]` will show you such rows.

Comment: This results in 8479801 rows, and not easy to find duplicated cases.

Comment: all of them are duplicated cases

Comment: you can chain `.sort_values(common_cols)` to see the same rows together.

Comment: last comment: `mapper = frame_B.groupby(common_cols)[target_col].agg(lambda vals: vals.iat[0] if vals.size == 1 else list(vals))` will aggregate the duplicate rows' values to a list (or leave as is if not duplicated) instead of dropping. Then you'll get both of the values, e.g., both `data` and `other` in the above example in a list `[data, other]`. Happy coding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247244/discussion-between-obiii-and-mustafa-aydin).

Answer (score 1):

Example dataframes:

```py
frame_A = pd.DataFrame({
    'OB_ID': [4, 4, 3], 
    'CA_ID': [4, 4, 5], 
    'col1': ['a', 'a', 'c'], 
    'col2': ['b', 'd', 'c'], 
    'col3': ['c', 'b', 'e']
})
frame_B = pd.DataFrame({
    'OB_ID': [3, 3, 4], 
    'CA_ID': [5, 5, 6], 
    'colZ': ['sky', 'air', 'stone']
})
common_cols = ['OB_ID','CA_ID']
```

#### Current behaviour

( just visualising it for better understanding )

Note that (as @MustafaAydın explained), `len(frame_A)` == 3. But since the pair `[3, 5]` of `['OB_ID', 'CA_ID']` repeats twice in `frame_B` - it is used twice when merging, and the length of the result becomes 4:

```py
pd.merge(frame_A, frame_B, on=common_cols, how='left')
```

|  | OB_ID | CA_ID | col1 | col2 | col3 | colZ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 | 4 | a | b | c | nan |
| 1 | 4 | 4 | a | d | b | nan |
| 2 | 3 | 5 | c | c | e | sky |
| 3 | 3 | 5 | c | c | e | air |

#### Possible Solution

Is this what you want?:

Using [`.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), you can choose only the first (of last) occurrences of rows in `frame_B` where `common_cols` are the same (between rows):

```py
frame_B_dropped = frame_B.drop_duplicates(common_cols)

pd.merge(frame_A, frame_B_dropped, on=common_cols, how='left')
```

|  | OB_ID | CA_ID | col1 | col2 | col3 | colZ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 | 4 | a | b | c | nan |
| 1 | 4 | 4 | a | d | b | nan |
| 2 | 3 | 5 | c | c | e | sky |

Here the length of the result should always equal `len(frame_A)`.